# Google Form to Create an Event in Calendar

Tags: google-apps-script, google-calendar-api, google-forms

I have created a Google Form for our local scout district, to notify that they will be taking the section out and about. This is all working fine as is the notification email. What I am trying to do is automatically create a calendar event, this will be later shared through out website so that the management team can view and see where all of the scouts are.

Anyway back on track, the fields that I have so far are:

```js
function CalendarSubmit(e){
  var Group = e.values[1];
  var ActivityDateStart = e.values[2];
  var ActivityTimeStart = e.values[3];
  var ActivityDateEnd = e.values[4];
  var ActivityTimeEnd = e.values[5];
  var Activity = e.values[6];
  var Location = e.values[7];
  var Description = e.values[8];
  var AuthLeader = e.values[9];
  var AuthLeaderNo = e.values[10];
  var AuthLeaderPermit = e.values[11];
  var LeaderCharge = e.values[12];
  var LeaderChargeNo = e.values[13];
  var LeaderEmail = e.values[14]
  var Adults = e.values[15];
  var Beavers = e.values[16];
  var Cubs = e.values[17];
  var Scouts = e.values[18];
  var Explorers = e.values[19];
  var Other = e.values[20];
  var InTouchName = e.values[21];
  var InTouchContact = e.values[22];
  var ManagerEmail = e.values[23];
  var RA = e.values[24];
  var Rules = e.values[25];
}
```

I want the calendar title to use the Variable Title, where

```js
var Title = group + " - " + Activity;
```

Start and Finish Times:

```js
var Start = ActivityDateStart + ActivityTimeStart;
var End = ActivityDateEnd + ActivityTimeEnd;
```

Location:

```js
var LOC = Location
```

Description:

```js
var calDescription = "Location of Activity: " + Activity + " /n" +
"Description of Activity: " + Description + " /n/n" +
"Leader in Charge: " + LeaderCharge + " /n" +
"No. of Adults (18+): " + Adults + " /n" +
"No. of Beavers: " + Beavers + " /n" +
"No. of Cubs: " + Cubs + " /n" +
"No. of Scouts: " + Scouts + " /n" +
"No. of Explorers/Young Leaders: " + Explorers + " /n" +
"No. of Non-Uniformed Young People (Under 18): " + Other;
```

The trouble I am having is that I am not sure how to script all of the above into the CalendarApp.